# When performing regex search within the array, it returns as empty

Tags: python, regex

When performing regex search within the array, it returns as empty

**SCRIPT**

```
array = ['GW-date45:ger-date45:mySAPgives','DC-date48ccc:date48:mySAP']

# REGEX
hostname = []
for node in array:
    hostname.append(re.findall(r'^[^-]*\K-([^:]+)', node))

for line in hostname:
    print(line)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[]
[]
```

[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/MMoOiM/1)

Comment: Remove `\K`. See https://ideone.com/hDRMD7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python `re` does not support [`\K` construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html).

It seems you do not even need it since all you need is the capturing group 1 values. Use

```
import re
array = ['GW-date45:ger-date45:mySAPgives','DC-date48ccc:date48:mySAP']
hostname = []
for node in array:
    m = re.search(r'^[^-]*-([^:]+)', node)
    if m:
        hostname.append(m.group(1))

for line in hostname:
    print(line)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/N101pF). Output:

```
date45
date48ccc
```